# A different kettle of fish

Tags: expressions

Am I using the expression *"A different kettle of fish"* correctly in the below example sentence?

> The first semester subjects were easy to learn. But the second
>   semester was *a different kettle of fish.*

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/90010/9161 https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/100052/9161 https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/64919/9161

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are absolutely correct in your usage.
[Idiom Definition 1](http://www.idioms4you.com/complete-idioms/kettle-of-fish.html)

"kettle of fish"

> an awkward, difficult, or bad situation;
>   a muddle;
>    a mess

[Idiom Definition 2](http://www.idioms4you.com/complete-idioms/kettle-of-fish.html)

"kettle of fish"

> a state of affairs;
>
> a matter under consideration